# Set result in ViewData using JQuery Ajax call in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am at learning phase and I am developing simple calculator using jquery and ajax in MVC and I want to show a result in viewdata["result"]. how can I do this? Please guide me.

Here is the **Example of code.**

```
**Model**

Models.calc c=new Models.calc(string n1,string n2);
c.num1=Convert.toInt32(n1);
c.num2=Convert.toInt32(n2);
int result=c.num1+c.num2;
viewdata["result"]=result;**

**iN AJAX , how i show this viewdata["result"] to show result in label.**

$.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("add", "Home")",
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'n1': number1, 'n2': number2 }),
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "JSON",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
             @ViewData["Result"];
           }, 
  error: function (err) {
           console.log(err);
         }
});
}**
```

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript ajax-request runs on the client side in the users browser.
you cannot access @ViewData["Result"] there, because it is a razor statement, which is interpreted on the server side.

You need to return your result in your controller action, which will be in your data variable.
After that you can pick your label, textbox or other element an set its value or innerHtml property in the "success"-part of your javascript.

e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "@(Url.Action("add", "Home"))",
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'n1': number1, 'n2': number2 }),
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "JSON",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
     $('#yourLabel').text(data); //<-- here, I look for a label with an ID
  }, 
  error: function (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
});
```